# Updating a field automatically on PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

I wonder if someone can help. I have a list hosted on SharePoint online to track statuses of projects. One of the columns show the current status, so "New", "In Progress", "Under Review" and so on. The list is managed through PowerApps. At present, this field "Status" is a single line of text.

My intention is that when an user access a record via PowerApps, they will need to update some fields. When they click on the "submit" button, the Status field on SharePoint will then be updated from "New" to "Under Review". When they navigate to other sections of the app, the Status field for this record will also be changed automatically depend on which option they selected.

I have tried all the functions that I can think of, but I can't seem to find one that would automatically set a specific status back to the SharePoint record that they are working on.

Would someone be able to help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onVisible and onHidden screen properties if necessary, you can also try Patch inside an If or Switch

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't think I got the syntex correctly. This is what I have on the OnSelect button: 

`code` 
Patch(Project, {ID_DataCard_ProjectRecord}, {Status: "Under Review"}) 

I also tried this: 

`code` 
Patch(Project, {ID: Value(ID_DataCard_ProjectRecord.Default)}, {Status: "Under Review"})

Basically, when an user is inside a record, they can select the "Under Review" button, which will change the Status field on the SharePoint column from one status to another. 

Would you be able to advise further? Thanks.

Comment: The Patch funcion receives 3 parameters: (Datasource, Record, Data) you are wrong on record, you can use Patch(Project, LookUp(Project, ID =  Value(ID_DataCard_ProjectRecord.Default),  {Status: "Under Review"})

Comment: Hi @pablo-infante, many thanks for this. I amended mine, but now it gives another message: "Invalid argument type. Expecting one of the following: Boolean, Number, Text, OptionSetValue." I assume that I have set an incorrect field type somewhere, would that be right? The ID field is on default (the one comes with SharePoint), so I haven't touched it. What else should I check? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Joe you must check the type of data in your sharepoint list, I sugest to use type Text or Number. The others data types like Choice are are more difficult to work with at first.

Comment: @Joe, the error you received two comments above is likely due to the missing ")" at the end of the code he gave you.

Comment: Many thanks for everyone's input, but something's still not quite right. The Status column is single line text, and ID is whatever it came with.